# How you prevent absolutely positioned child inside relative container from overflowing?

Tags: css

I hope my question is clear enough: I got a containing div of elements that I wanna treat as an unique block of elements all moving to the left of my navigation bar. Inside of this parent div I have two ul elements, a separator span element and an input box that I wanna make the same height of the container and would like to make of variable width cause as it is by default it does never resize and looks horrible when screen width changes. What I tried is to make the parent div relatively positioned and made the input position absolute, with 100% height; what happened is that now the contained element appears as if it was outside of the containing div (border red in this image)

[image]

While my idea was to use the red-bordered div in order to force the input to resize. How do I achieve this? I can provide my code but since I can bet it will have to be completely rewritten to fit this purpose I'm not sure if it would use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flexbox

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
}

li{
    margin-left:5px;
}

.flex{
  display:flex;
  border:solid 1px #f00;
  padding-left:10px;
}

input{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Or, by giving the input element `box-sizing:border-box`:

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
}

li{
    margin-left:5px;
}

.flex{
  position:relative;
  border:solid 1px #f00;
  padding-left:10px;
}

input{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: since in our lecure we haven't faced flexes yet, is there any valid alternative to it?

Comment: @Bafforasta look at the second example in my answer. Make `input` `box-sizing:border-box`